# Correct usage of came across

Tags: word-usage

Which of the following sounds more natural:

> I came across with something rather interesting

or

> I came across something rather interesting

and are these both correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Oxford Dictionary of English (2nd Ed 2006) states :

> Appear or sound in a specified way; give a specified impression.

Example : He'd always come across as a decent sort.

It then also lists 'come across' as

> Meet or find by chance

and gives the example : I came across these old photos recently.

So your second sentence is correct.

'He came across something interesting' means that he discovered something interesting unintentionally.

If one wanted to express that he had *communicated something interesting,* then that would need to be expressed in another way.

[The correct one sounds more natural to myself, but that is just my own impression.]

Answer (score 4):

We can only judge the 'naturalness' of an expression when we know its context and intended meaning. There are at least three possible contexts:

**Context 1:** You tell your spouse that you found something interesting earlier in the day (for example when shopping or surfing the web):

> I came across something rather interesting.

This uses the phrasal verb '*to come across*' meaning:

> - to meet someone, or to find something by chance.

http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/come-across

**Context 2**: You tell your spouse about a meeting earlier in the day when you put forward a novel suggestion:

> I came across with something rather interesting.

This uses the less common phrasal verb '*to come across with*'.

> - to provide something that is needed or wanted

http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/come-across-with

**Context 3**: You are relating a story in which you crossed a river with something you found on the other side.

> I came across with something rather interesting.

This uses the simple verb '*come*' followed by the adverb '*across*' and the prepositional phrase beginning with '*with*'.

I suspect that you are asking *Context 1* above. It is interesting to note, however, that there are several examples in Google of the phrase '*came across with*' with the first meaning above - i.e. *to find something by chance*. For example:

> - Some time ago I came across with a problem.
> - I'm happy that I came across with your site ... .
> - I came across with a really great article by Claire Lew ... .
> - While reading my Facebook news feed, I came across with a post of the Polytechnic Institute ... .

This does not sound right to me as a British English native speaker, but may be common in other dialects. Of course, the Google examples may also have been written by non-native speakers who were using the wrong phrasal verb.

Comment: This is one of comprehensive answers.